# pyparsing not working on windows text file but works on linux text file

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a simple pyparsing construct for extracting parts of a log message. It looks like this

`log_line = timestamp + task_info + Suppress(LineEnd())`

This construct parses a log file generated in Linux very well but doesn't parse a similar file generated in windows. I am pretty sure it is because of the new line representation difference. I was wondering if `LineEnd()` takes care of that? If it doesn't how do I take care of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Suppress("\r\n")` instead of `Suppress(LineEnd())`

Comment: Or since `\r` and `\n` are whitespace, you might need to write that as `Suppress(White("\r\n"))`. I think LineEnd does alright parsing line endings in files created in the same platform you are running on, but isn't so good at guessing line endings for files that come from other platforms.